# MVC: Unable to update one of my model's properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, getter-setter

In my mvc controller, I'm  using a model for Orders.  One of the properties in my Order model is called StatusDesc (Status Description).  When I originally pull this status via the database, it populates my model, including this StatusDesc property successfully, however if I later go to update the StatusDesc via code, it doesn't update & I'm not sure why.  Here's my code:
Going into this code, the StatusDesc = "Completed"

My Order model:

```
private string _statusDesc;

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string StatusDesc
    {
        get { return GetOrderHelper.GetOrderStatusDesc(this); }
        set { _statusDesc = value; }
    }
```

My OrderHelper class contains a method to help determine the order's status (Completed, Active, or Deleted):

```
public class OrderHelper
{
    public string GetOrderStatusDesc(Order order)
    {
        return order.CompletedDate != null ? "Completed" : (order.Active ? "Active" : "Deleted");
    }
}
```

In my controller, I try to update the Order model's StatusDesc however, & it won't update.

```
//Before code is run --> order.StatusDesc = "Completed"
 order.StatusDesc = "Pending";
 //After code is run --> order.StatusDesc = "Completed"
```

What am I doing wrong that would prevent my StatusDesc from updating to "Pending"?

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind to tell what data access method do you use? Maybe Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2):

because you are reading StatusDesc value from other property.

```
return order.CompletedDate != null ? "Completed" : (order.Active ? "Active" : "Deleted");
```

StatusDesc values is based on CompletedDate  value;

Answer (score 0):

You are returning either "Completed", "Active", and "Deleted".
Even if you update the StatusDesc it will never return the value that was used to update it.
You might need a condition that says if the StatusDesc is not null or empty then return StatusDesc.